# What acoustic properties of sounds enable us to distinguish the owner of the voice?

Tags: signal-analysis, acoustics

Different people reading the same sentences, we can know from the voice who is speaking.

What makes the voice distinguishable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible perceivable differences might include:

- differences in pitch frequency (bass vs. soprano voice, etc.)
- differences in overtone series (formants, head resonances, accent)
- variations in modulation of pitch over time (vibrato, tremolo, accent)
- differences in voiced to unvoiced ratios (raspiness?)
- variations in typical durations of each vowel or consonant
- variations in cadence modulation (accent?)
- differences in choice of phonemes for each word or phrase (accent?)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve your problem would be to record a short sentence and then calculate the FFT. This will give you an average spectral fingerprint for that person. Then you can compare spectra in order to identify a given person.

Check some more details here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint